# Darwin: how to kill parent process without killing child?

Tags: unix, macos, bsd

On OS X 10.4/5/6:

I have a parent process which spawns a child.  I want to kill the parent without killing the child.  Is it possible?   I can modify source on either app.

Comment: In re: voting for ServerFault. I just don't see it. Either SuperUser if he need to learn about `nohup (1)`, or stay here if this is about signal catching and handling in the child process.

Comment: @NSD:  the parent app calls system("command line").  Both apps are running in an ordinary user's account.

@jldupont:  Sorry, I don't know that trick.  Unix is my second language :)

Comment: I should mention that the parent app is a C program, not a shell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As NSD asked, it really depends on how it is spawned.  If you are using a shell script, for example, you can use the `nohup` command to run the child through.

If you are using `fork/exec`, then it is a little more complicated, but no too much so.

From http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66012/

```
import sys, os 

def main():
    """ A demo daemon main routine, write a datestamp to 
        /tmp/daemon-log every 10 seconds.
    """
    import time

    f = open("/tmp/daemon-log", "w") 
    while 1: 
        f.write('%s\n' % time.ctime(time.time())) 
        f.flush() 
        time.sleep(10) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # do the UNIX double-fork magic, see Stevens' "Advanced 
    # Programming in the UNIX Environment" for details (ISBN 0201563177)
    try: 
        pid = os.fork() 
        if pid > 0:
            # exit first parent
            sys.exit(0) 
    except OSError, e: 
        print >>sys.stderr, "fork #1 failed: %d (%s)" % (e.errno, e.strerror) 
        sys.exit(1)

    # decouple from parent environment
    os.chdir("/") 
    os.setsid() 
    os.umask(0) 

    # do second fork
    try: 
        pid = os.fork() 
        if pid > 0:
            # exit from second parent, print eventual PID before
            print "Daemon PID %d" % pid 
            sys.exit(0) 
    except OSError, e: 
        print >>sys.stderr, "fork #2 failed: %d (%s)" % (e.errno, e.strerror) 
        sys.exit(1) 

    # start the daemon main loop
    main()
```

This is one of the best books ever written.  It covers these topics in great and extensive detail.

**Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment, Second Edition (Addison-Wesley Professional Computing Series) (Paperback)**

ISBN-10: 0321525949
ISBN-13: 978-0321525949

5 star amazon reviews (I'd give it 6).

Comment: The parent isn't a shell, it's a C application calling system().  Is there  solution for that?

Answer (score 4):

If the parent is a shell, and you want to launch a long running process then logout, consider `nohup (1)` or `disown`.

If you control the coding of the child, you can trap SIGHUP and handling it in some non-default way (like ignoring it outright). Read the `signal (3)` and `sigaction (2)` man pages for help with this. Either way there are several existing questions on StackOverflow with good help.

Comment: Ooops... the parent isn't a shell, sorry.  It's a C app calling system().  I have control of the source for both apps, but I don't know how to prevent the death of the parent from killing the child.